# unable to get mysql working with django

Tags: python, mysql, django

I am trying to learn Django. I have some programming experience but I am new to Django and python. I have installed Django and now trying to connect it with MySQL. I have also installed MAMP and created the database and also edited the settings.py. But I am getting following error when I am trying to run Django:

> django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: Error loading MySQLdb module: No module named MySQLdb

I have added following in settings.py:

```
DATABASES = {
'default': {
    'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',
    'NAME': 'mysitedb',
    'USER': 'root',
    'PASSWORD': 'root',
    'HOST': 'localhost',
    }
}
```

Am I missing something? I have checked on google and I can see a thread to install python-mysql using following command in terminal:

> pip install MySQL-python

But this command doesn't run for me and I get following error:

```
Command python setup.py egg_info failed with error code 1 in /private/var/folders/1n/1r7lvnh53k5g46zpl3jsvz7h0000gr/T/pip_build_pankaj/MySQL-python
Storing complete log in /Users/pankaj/Library/Logs/pip.log
```

P.S: I am using Mac OS 10.9.

Answer (score 1):

I had similar issue with `python3` and `Django 1.9` on Mac-

Run:

`$ pip install mysqlclient`

*If still doesn't work then try:*

`export PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/mysql/bin`

or whatever is your mysql path
for me it was
`/usr/local/Cellar/mysql/5.6.26/bin`

https://github.com/PyMySQL/mysqlclient-python

Answer (score 0):

```
sudo apt-get install python-mysqldb
```

use [django the definitive guide](http://www.amazon.in/The-Definitive-Guide-Django-Development/dp/1590597257). It is very simple for beginner

for mac user

```
sudo pip install MySQL-python
```

Comment: OP is using a Mac so `apt-get` is not appropriate

Comment: sudo pip install MySQL-python

Comment: when I try to run above command I get EnvironmentError: mysql_config not found

Comment: and then... Command python setup.py egg_info failed with error code 1 in /private/tmp/pip_build_root/MySQL-python

Comment: install libmariadbclient-dev
and use sudo python setup.py 

it seems mysql_config is missing on your system or installer could not find it.
export PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/mysql/bin
it will help you

Comment: using sudo pip i Get.  command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in /private/tmp/pip-build-_Ukxtj/MySQL-python

Answer (score 0):

My suspicion is that running `sudo pip install MySQL-python` would fix your issue.

That said, a better option would be to install [virtualenv](http://www.virtualenv.org/en/latest/), create a dev environment and then install Django and all required modules such as MySQL-python. Doing so would remove the need to install modules with `sudo`, with the added bonus that it is much easier to rollback or even just to nuke an environment if it all goes horribly wrong.

Comment: To fix your new error, try running `export PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/mysql/bin` and then try `sudo pip install mysql-python` again

Answer (score 0):

Possibly some mysql libs are missing, just install with

```
brew install mysql
```

and then install MySQL-python with pip